# Best sql (or other) database design for very large table, thousands of rows by thousands of columns

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm about to build a web app to retrieve values from biological gene expression data. The table that I'm using to populate the database is 27,000 rows labeled as gene IDs `gene_A`, `gene_B`, `gene_C` `etc...`, and 50,000 columns labeled as cells `cell_1`, `cell_2`, `cell_3`, `etc...`. Each gene has a float value for each cell ranging between 0 and 1. I'd like to query based on the gene or the cell.

I'm newish to sql and have read that a one to many database design is appropriate here. But would I need a new table for each of the 50,000 cells or each of the 27,000 genes? How would that affect performance? The only other design I can think of is to have a table with the gene IDS as rows and a single column 'cell_expression' that contains JSON of the 50,000 cell values. But this might limit my queries to the gene IDs only?

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: most modern database engines support JSON storage and great indexing and parsing on JSON documents it might help if you tag your RDMS product and version

Answer (score 1):

You want one table with two key columns:  `gene_id` and `cell`.  It is not clear if there is other data.  For instance, if the data is just a flag, then just having the name of the cell might be sufficient.  Or you might want a value.

By the way, many databases put limits on the number of columns in a table -- and that limit is usually around 1,000 or so.  You will need to restructure the data before you import it, depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have one gene expression data spreadsheet.  If you have more, this answer will need an additional SQL table.

First, I'd create a Cell table.

```
Cell
----
Cell ID
Cell Name or descriptor
```

The Cell ID is an auto-incrementing integer that is used as the primary key to the table.  According to your description, this table would have 50,000 rows.

Next, I'd create a Gene table.

```
Gene
----
Gene ID
Gene Name or descriptor.
```

The structure of the Gene table is similar to the structure of the Cell table.  According to your description, this table would have 27,000 rows.

Finally, we create the CellValue table.

```
CellValue
---------
Cell ID
Gene ID
Cell Value
```

The primary index is (Cell ID, Gene ID).  You would also have a unique index on (Gene ID, Cell ID).  The primary index allows you to retrieve all the cell values for a cell name.  The unique index allows you to retrieve all the cell values for a gene name.

If you select for a gene and a cell, you'll get one value back.

Now, this table will contain 1,350,000,000 rows for one spreadsheet.  I hope you have the storage for this.